# Se desea realizar la rotación de 90 grados en el sentido de las manecillas del reloj de una matriz que almacena números enteros

Tags: c++

Se desea realizar la rotación de 90 grados en el sentido de las manecillas del reloj de una matriz que almacena números enteros. Se debe imprimir en una línea los números separados por un espacio (NOTA: no debe colocar el espacio después del último número) de cada renglón de la matriz, la cual debe estar rotada 90 grados en el sentido de las manecillas del reloj.
Este es mi código, pero me dice que no estoy contemplando todos los casos:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define FIL 7
#define COL 7
#define MAX 50

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    int matriz[FIL][COL]={0};
    int *matriz2[FIL][COL]={NULL};
    int fil1=0,col1=0;
    int i=0,j=0,k=0,w=0;
    
    scanf("%d",&fil1);
    col1=fil1;
    
    for(i=0;i<fil1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<col1;j++){
            scanf("%d",&matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }
    
    k=0;
    w=0;    
    
    for(j=0;j<fil1;j++){
        for(i=fil1-1;i>=0;i--){
            matriz2[k][w]=&matriz[i][j];
            w++;
            
        }
        k++;
        w=0;
    }   
    
    for(i=0;i<fil1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<col1;j++){
            printf("%d ",*matriz2[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");   
    }   
    printf("%d ",*matriz2[i][j]);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Supongo que es porque el ejercicio no especifica que las matrices sean cuadradas. Aunque tampoco especifica qué hacer cuando no son cuadradas, pero me imagino que debería ser igual que sacar la transpuesta de la matriz de `(n, m)` y obtener una matriz de `(m, n)` (la dimensión de la transupesta, o en este caso la rotada)

Comment: ¿Seguro que tu pregunta es [tag:c++]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No estás contemplando el caso de que la matriz no sea cuadrada. Para hacer tu código más flexible y seguro, yo usaría plantillas:

```
template <typename T, auto FIL, auto COL>
void rotar_90_derecha(const T (&origen)[FIL][COL], T (&destino)[COL][FIL])
{
    auto columna = FIL - 1;

    for (const auto &fila : origen)
    {
        for (auto indice = 0u; indice < COL; ++indice)
        {
            destino[indice][columna] = fila[indice];
        }
        --columna;
    }
}
```

Observa que el origen está organizado con filas y columnas, mientras que el destino lo está en columnas filas; esto es porque al girar 90º las filas pasan a ser columnas y viceversa.

La función anterior puede usarse así:

```
int main()
{
    int a[3][3]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int b[3][3]{};

    rotar_90_derecha(a, b);

    muestra(a);
    std::cout << '\n';
    muestra(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Que muestra la siguiente salida:

> ```
> 1 2 3
> 4 5 6
> 7 8 9
>
> 7 4 1
> 8 5 2
> 9 6 3
> ```

Funciona también con matrices rectangulares:

```
int main()
{
    int c[5][2]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int d[2][5]{};

    rotar_90_derecha(c, d);

    muestra(c);
    std::cout << '\n';
    muestra(d);

    return 0;
}
```

> ```
> 0 1
> 2 3
> 4 5
> 6 7
> 8 9
>
> 8 6 4 2 0
> 9 7 5 3 1
> ```

Dado que la plantilla comprueba implícitamente las dimensiones de origen y destino, obtendrás un fallo de compilación cuando la matriz no pueda ser rotada:

```
rotar_90_derecha(a, d);
```

> ```
> error: no matching function for call to 'rotar_90_derecha'
>    rotar_90_derecha(a, d);
>    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting values for parameter 'FIL' (3 vs. 5)
> ```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZLfS8MwEMefm7/iQNCNpTCn88e67UUQBMGXvdUyYprNQJuMNBV09F@3XtIUJk5E2tLe3efuvncN3@1iXjC1bdsTqXhR5wLmUlfWCFYuCbGi3BXMotO@74RipYAVBVZbDfcPj@Hr7ulxSd60zMFoy8z6drzOhRH8lQ24VpWFFQxOtZFboYYppmUpZmTUu3NRWan00Lt8cEj2JPJ1uS7qUjFYuF4Qw3lCSLTRBkJZD51uZMFgBqE@iTC7g3xYqlxygSXGddIbc6c4gdGoszHHJ0VBS9q5szT0zzDbNen9CbINPnEcAHQ0pPn3ssoa@5nDHZXMGvlxsCO/i98mDvTBxIfQGyvQNfPK3YRRZfPZjOvawnwOZ3jhy0Nunu/BZ3XWzySVxUZSDbwUZ7H0IsN7f05hQuGCwiWFKYUrCtcUbijcNkkHvgSwcb/tx8lgFF6GLtKvgaF1VEcPdPgxwnXj6TRLJ9l@TOFPZTmCiP@ijFPIvynjfynr8GMjhoiwtVEwTkjTtp98U7Bt1cZYccFHown7Ag)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes ya te lo han dicho, no estás leyendo el número de columnas y asumes que las matrices son cuadradas.

Esto te genera varios problemas:

- En el caso de matrices cuadradas el resultado obtenido es incorrecto porque, al no leer el número de columnas, ese dato se lee como el correspondiente a la posición `[0][0]` de la matriz, desplazando el resto de valores y dejando fuera al último.
- En el caso de matrices rectangulares, si el número de filas es inferior al número de columnas, te dejaras valores sin leer (aparte del hecho de que la matriz con la que trabajas será cuadrada). El resultado obtenido será incorrecto
- En el caso de que el número de filas sea superior al de columnas intentarás leer más valores de los que hay en el caso de prueba, por lo que tu programa se quedará esperando valores y no terminará nunca (o, si la entrada estándar se redirecciona a un archivo, obtendrás un bonito mensaje de error).

Por otro lado, piensa que no necesitas leer una matriz y luego rotarla, basta con almacenar los datos en su posición final:

```
int rows, columns;
std::cin >> columns >> rows; // Leemos las dimensiones de la matriz rotada

int ** matrix = new int*[rows];
for( int i=0; i<rows; i++ )
    matrix[i] = new int[columns];

for( int j=columns-1; j>=0; j-- )
{
    for( int i=0; i<rows; i++ )
    {
        std::cin >> matrix[i][j];
    }
}

for( int i=0; i<rows; i++ )
{
    for( int j=0; j<columns; j++ )
    {
        if( j > 0 ) std::cout << ' ';
        std::cout << matrix[i][j];
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

for( int i=0; i<rows; i++ )
    delete[] matrix[i];
delete[] matrix;
```

Answer (score 0):

Este es mi codigo, que implemento para hacer la rotación.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define REN 30
#define COL 30
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int MATRIZ[REN][COL];  //se declara una matriz de 30x30
    int m,n,renglon,columna;
    
    scanf("%d",&n); //leer desde teclado el valor n=renglones
    scanf("%d",&m); //leer desde teclado el valor m=columnas
    
    //Implementamos un ciclo para leer los valores de la matriz

    for (renglon=0;renglon<n;renglon++){
        for(columna=0;columna<m;columna++){
            scanf ("%d",&MATRIZ[renglon][columna]);
        }
    }
    
        
    return 0;
}
```